# haskell my last line “putStr" threw error

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char

isIn :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
needle `isIn` haystack = any (needle `isPrefixOf` ) (tails haystack)


encode :: Int -> String -> String
encode offset msg = map (\c -> chr $ ord c + offset) msg

main :: IO()
main =
     if "arts" `isIn` "artsisgood" then 
        putStrLn "is in"
     else
        putStrLn "not in"

     putStr (encode 3 "hey")
```

My last line makes compiler throw err. What's wrong with it?

Comment: If you encounter an error / you might be in terror / but don't go and haste / please copy and paste (your error).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 problems:

- Indentation was bad for your if statement
- you didn't chain your 2 operations (see examples below)

Your code fixed:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char

isIn :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
needle `isIn` haystack = any (needle `isPrefixOf` ) (tails haystack)


encode :: Int -> String -> String
encode offset = map (\c -> chr $ ord c + offset)
-- encode offset msg = map (\c -> chr $ ord c + offset) msg

main :: IO()
main = do
     if "arts" `isIn` "artsisgood" 
       then putStrLn "is in"
       else putStrLn "not in"
     putStr (encode 3 "hey")

main2 =
   if "arts" `isIn` "artsisgood" 
   then putStrLn "is in"
   else putStrLn "not in"
   >> putStr (encode 3 "hey")
```

Answer (score 0):

From your indentation, it seems like you're trying to write in `do` notation. Just adding the keyword `do` fixes your code:

```
main :: IO()
main = do
     if "arts" `isIn` "artsisgood" then 
        putStrLn "is in"
     else
        putStrLn "not in"

     putStr (encode 3 "hey")
```